# How to force tabnavigator screen to re-render in react-native

Tags: view, tabs, tabnavigator

I'm new to react-native.

I have a main screen with 2 tabs:  "NYT Book List" and "My Book List" (Please see attached image).

When I press the "Add to List" button on a NYT Book List item, I want to update the list for "My Book List" with that selection. I'm using a global variable defined in my Globals.js (myBooks = new Map(); global.myBooks = myBooks ) shared by both tab screens to keep track of my selections.

I've been trying different ways to make "My Book List" to re-render every time the tab is pressed, with no success. I understand the RN design is to only re-render when there's a props or state change. I think I've tried that, not sure if I did that right though.

Can someone please tell me what do I need to code to force a tab view re-render?

Thanks.

Here's my router.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import BookList from './BookList'
import BookDetails from './BookDetails';
import MyList from './MyList'
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator(
  {
    BookListScreen: { 
      screen: BookList, 

       navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({title: "New York Times Book List", 
                              tabBarLabel: "NYT Book List",
                              tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="list" size={35} color={tintColor} />,

          }),   


      },

    MyListsScreen: { 

        screen:  MyList,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation})  => ({
                              title: "My Book List", 
                              tabBarLabel: "My Book List",
                              tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="loyalty" size={35} color={tintColor} />,


          }),   



      },
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: 
    {
      showIcon: true
    }
  }
);



export const Root = StackNavigator({
  LandingScreen: {
    screen: MainScreenNavigator,

  },
  BookDetailsScreen: {
    screen: BookDetails,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: `Book Details`,
    }),
  },
  MyListScreen: {
    screen: MyList,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: `My Book List`,
    }),
  },
});
```

[Screen shot of screen with the tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJd3W.png)